# Change DB connection string after publishing a C# console app

Tags: c#, connection-string

1. I have a development environment connection string in App.config
   file of my C# console application.
2. What I need is to abe able to change the connection string after
   publishing the the application.
3. Whenever I publish, a manifest file is created along that has some
   hash keys in it and if I try to change the config files, it throws
   an error stating `it has a different computed hash than specified in manifest`.

How to get around this problem

Comment: Why do you need to change the connection string after publishing? Can you not just publish it with the correct Connection string? If you need to change the conn string regurlarly, then maybe consider storing it as a `string` rather than a `ConnectionString`

Comment: The DB might change in future..so need to make it configurable...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm looking for a solution for this too.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading it from a database table instead. Also, if other apps in the future could use this connection string in the future it would be nice to just have to make the change once. You could also utilize the same logic across your apps to retrieve the connection string. If this does not sound reasonable for your case, I agree with Simon when he said 'if you need to change the conn string regurlarly, then maybe consider storing it as a string'. You could even try setting it as an Environment variable if needed.